# NestJS: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma, prisma-graphql

```
import { INestApplication, Injectable, OnModuleInit} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Prisma, PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient implements OnModuleInit {
    async onModuleInit() {
        await this.$connect();
    }

    async enableShutdownHooks(app: INestApplication) {
        this.$on('beforeExit', async () => {
          await app.close();
        });
    }
}
```

i got error on the line `this.$on('beforeExit', async () => {` as it was saying *Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'*

I tried so many things from stackoverflow but couldn't resolved it. Please help me.

It should have work as fine.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/20171